# Oracle OBIEE Analytics

Tags: obiee

I can not access the web interfaces of obiee. Any suggestions or solutions?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the service is running and listening on port 7001?

Comment: Are you using the right URL? For example:  `http://localhost:7001/analytics`, or `http://localhost:7001/console`

Comment: Make sure which OBIEE version you are using.

Comment: Moreover its never localhost.com, rather it is localhost.

Make sure never use localhost, rather you can use the host ip address

Answer (score 1):

"www".localhost:7001 should just be localhost:7001.

Also, OBIEE runs on the /analytics deoloyment. /console is the WebLogic administration console.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the correct URL:

Use this URL:
`http://localhost:7001/analytics`

instead of:
`http://www.localhost.com:7001/console`

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your URL is apt or not.

Because what I think it should be `localhost:7001/em` or `localhost:7001/console` which is Enterprise Manager and Weblogic Console respectively.

And for OBIEE web page, we use analytics that is nothing but `localhost:9704/analytics` or `localhost:9502/analytics`

Solely depends on your OBIEE configuration.

Hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot it appears as if you are attempting to access weblogic console. I would make sure that node manager and Admin Server are both started and running. On Windows os, click on the start menu and type NodeManager/Start Weblogic and it will give you the shortcut icons.

Once those two have been started you should be able to login to weblogic console and to ensure that admin/managed servers are both running.

If you did an enterprise installation of OBIEE11g, the default port for analytics should be 9704 unless you manually configured to use a different port number.